# Power of hypoteses test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am having some problems calculating the power in this exercise.

http://snag.gy/LkulQ.jpg

[image]

This is what i've tried. 
So since i know that $\alpha$ is 0.05. I thereby know that the upper boundary is given by the formula 0.05 has a Z-score = 1.64485

$$ 1.64485 =\frac{\bar{x} - 4}{50/\sqrt{9}} \Rightarrow  \bar{x} = 31.414166666666667` % note I already here knows that something is wrong$$

Then i calculate $\beta$ by 
$P(z \ge \frac{31.41417 - 4.5}{50/\sqrt{9}}) = 0.0531694$
and thereby the power beeing $1- 0.0531694 = 0.946831 $
This doesn't match what the "cheat sheet" => it says 1.. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the "cheat sheet" say ? And why is the denominator $50 \text{/} \sqrt{9}$ ? Do you want to solve c) ?

Comment: There is a stats website in the stackexchange group, Cross Validated.

Comment: @calculus it says 1, and denomiator is the denominator to calculate the test statistics.

Comment: @Kilroy I have made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The hypotheses are:

$H_0: \mu=4$

$H_A: \mu=4.5$

***Calculating the critical value. Above it we do not accept $H_0$***

We are only interested at the upper bound of the interval. If we standardized the random variable, we get 
$$\Phi \left( \frac{\overline x_c-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)=\Phi \left(\frac{\overline x_c-4}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{50}}}\right)=0.95$$

$\Phi(\cdot)$ ist the function of the standard normal distribution.

Note, that the standard deviation of $\overline x
$ is $\large{\sigma_{\overline x}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$

$\frac{\overline x_c-4}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{50}}}=\Phi (0.95)=1.645$

If you solve the equation, you will get $\overline x_c=4.047$.

**Calculating the probability of rejecting $H_A$, given $H_A$ is true**

Now we assume, that $\overline x$ is $\mathcal N\left( 4.5,\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{50}} \right) ^2 \right)$ distributed.

$\beta$ is the probability, that we accept $H_0$, given that $H_A$ is true.

Thus we calculate $\beta=\Phi \left(\frac{4.047-4.5}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{50}}}\right)$

After you have calculated $\beta$, you can calculate $1-\beta$.

I have added a sketch.

[image]